# Which one should I report as total network I/O bytes among Sum(InBound) or Sum(InBound + OutBound)?

Tags: computer-networks, experimental-analysis

I have a set of experiments with distributed environments.

I am planning to present a total network I/O bytes usage of the system for each run.

Which one should I report as total network I/O bytes among Sum(InBound Traffic) or Sum(InBound Traffic + OutBound Traffic)?

For example, say there are two machines A and B in my cluster server.

A sends 10 bytes to B.

B sends 15 bytes to A.

What is the total network I/O bytes? Is it 25 or 50 bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest reporting the sum of both.

As a general principle, the best solution is to *define your metrics* in the report or paper where you write up your results.  You should describe *what you measured* and *how you measured it*.  This includes clarifying whether "total network I/O" includes both inbound+outbound traffic or only inbound traffic.